# AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation not gives path value when restMethod uses GetMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor, spring-annotations

I was trying to setup usage of REST APIs in one of our application. SO I was trying to achieving this with interceptor approach.

The problem i was having as we are having two kinds of restful definitions spread-ed across controllers. some of them are with @Get/@post mappings while others with verbose `@RequestMapping`.

So when i use `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, RequestMapping.class)` we are not getting the path value where we are using HttpVerb maapings (`@GETMapping`).

My Solution for this is if we are getting empty path with `@RequestMapping`, then go to switch case and then check with each Http Verb, and then call the associated  `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, HttpVerbMapping.class)`. I am posting here, is there any better and simpler solution for this?

```
@GetMapping("/say-good-bye")
public ResponseEntity<String> sayGoodBye1() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Good bye see you later");
    }
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/say-good-bye2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> sayGoodBye2() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Good bye see you later");
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyOwnInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        Method method = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethod();

        RequestMapping requestMapping = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, RequestMapping.class);
        }
}
```

When i use  `curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/say-good-bye'` the `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, RequestMapping.class)` its returning empty path.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve, whyu do you need to annotation information? That being said the `@RequestMapping` should just work also for the other annotations if you use a recent enough Spring version.

Comment: When i use specifically ```AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, @RequestMapping.class)``` on the method annotated with ```@GetMapping``` i was not able to get the path information.

Comment: It shoudl as it is a meta annotation and the `findAnnotation` looks for meta annotations as well. At least if you use a decent recent enough version of Spring. So which version of Spring (Boot) are you using? I also suspect that the 2 methods you posted are only part of the problem and we need to see the whole controller. Nonetheless the usecase of what you are trying to achieve still isn't clear.

Comment: I was on ```2.7.14``` , let me check with the latest

Comment: That should do a look on meta-annotations already. So it seems you haven't shown the full picture but just snippets of look-alike code which doesn't have the problem.

Comment: I tried with Latest 2.7.16, still same issue. Can i share the reproducable repo link for quick check

Comment: I'm not going to go through your full code (unless you hire me to do so), include the needed information in your question.

Comment: i  don't require you to hire me . but if you consider to provide enough bounties for the question , i am happy to take a look . cheers.